# How to add multiple lists together, while keeping them as elements in Python?

Tags: python, list, data-manipulation

I have a large number of lists, with different sizes that I would like to join together. I need to be able to retrieve each specific original list by order. For example

```
list1 = ['apple', 'orange', 'mango']
list2 = ['banana', 'melon']
result: [['apple', 'orange', 'mango'], ['banana', 'melon']]
```

And then, I need to be able to do:

```
result[1]
['banana', 'melon']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`append` function](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists) will do this for you. Try something like:

```py
result = []
result.append(list1)
result.append(list2)
# ...
# append other lists here
# ...

# this will equal list1
result[1]
```

Answer (score 2):

Result is a list, in which you append your list in the order you choose:

```
list1 = ['apple', 'orange', 'mango']
list2 = ['banana', 'melon']

result = []
result.append(list1)
result.append(list2)
print(result)
[['apple', 'orange', 'mango'], ['banana', 'melon']]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this very simply like following.

```
result = [list1, list2]
```

Then `result` will be a list of lists.